# Display collaboration with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I would like to display the "collaboration" field of `biblatex` when present, for example:

```
@article{Aad2011150,
title = "TITLE",
author= {Aad, Georges and others},
collaboration = {ATLAS}
...
}
```

is shown as "G. Aad and others, TITLE, ...". I would like to have "G. Add and others (ATLAS collaboration), TITLE ..."

For other cases when the author is not present I would like to have: "ATLAS collaboration, TITLE ..."

is it possible? I'm using

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric-comp,backref, sorting=none, firstinits=true]{biblatex}
```

*I cannot use biber.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Biblatex: collaborator(s) field](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67898/biblatex-collaborators-field)

Comment: Please let us know if @Werner's link resolves the issue- at the moment it looks very likely that your question will be closed; if your question is different, please edit :)

Comment: no, it is not the same question, I'm talking about "Collaboration", not "Collaborators"

Comment: Any reason you can't replace "collaborators" with "collaboration" in that answer and follow the steps _exactly_ as given?

Comment: sorry, it is not easy for me. In addition I want an additional logic, as I asked: if authors are specified I want `AUTHORS (COLLABORATION collaboration)` else only `COLLABORATION`.

Comment: and in addition I cannot use bibel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can't use biber, no new fields such as `collaboration` can be introduced. For your entry example it seems that the group of physicists working on ATLAS actually go by the name "ATLAS collaboration". When they publish under this institutional name, wrap it in braces in the author list:

```
author = {{ATLAS collaboration}},
```

For articles where members of the group publish under their individual names, you can identify them as part of the ATLAS collaboration using the existing `authortype` field:

```
authortype = {ATLAS collaboration},
```

Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,maxnames=1]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  andothers = {and others}}

% adapted from biblatex.def
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifuseauthor} and not test {\ifnameundef{author}} }
    {\printnames{author}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
    {}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key1,
  author = {Aad, Georges and Brown, Bob and Doe, John},
  authortype = {ATLAS collaboration},
  title = {Authors from institution},
  journal = {Journal name},
  year = {1994}}
@book{key2,
  author = {{ATLAS collaboration}},
  title = {Institutional author},
  year = {1980}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{key1} showed that... \textcite{key2} showed that...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no new fields can be introduced?"

Comment: @mafp `collaboration` isn't a field defined in the default data model. You can only extend this model using biber.

Comment: this is unfortunate as `collaboration` is used by the de-facto standard for citations in high energy physics (inspirehep.net).

Answer (score 0):

arXiv has provided some bibliography style files that accommodate e-print fields and collaboration fields: https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles/