# use `collaboration` field with biblatex and biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, arxiv

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94877/display-collaboration-with-biblatex?noredirect=1&lq=1), I'd like to show the `collaboration` field (as provided by [e.g. inspire](http://inspirehep.net/record/1489630/export/hx)) in the citations using biblatex. In contrast to the linked question, I want to use biber, so cannot use the bibtex styles provided by arxiv (or in house bst styles).

How can I instruct biblatex with biber to show

```
<collaboration>, <author> "<title>" ...
```

I do not want to edit the .bib file to replace `collaboration` by `authortype` (as my .bib files are updated centrally for me and many colleagues for our in house bst style file).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this link](http://spamspameggsandspam.blogspot.ch/2013/04/convincing-biblatex-to-handle.html), I achieve this with the following code after `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
  \map{
    \step[fieldsource=Collaboration, final=true]
    \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval, final=true]
  }
 }
}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \iffieldundef{usera}{%
    \printnames{author}%
  }{%
    \printfield{usera}, \printnames{author}%
  }%
}%
```