# Why is Biber 2.8 so much slower than Biber 2.7?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a document with ~200 references. Some of the author fields are rather large. With Biber 2.7 a biber run took about 5-10 sec. With Biber 2.8 this takes now ~3 min.

Are their new features or options in Biber 2.8 / biblatex 3.8a which could cause such a behaviour and could be turned off?

How could I tell biber to truncate long author fields before processing it?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{CMS_experiment,
    author        = {S Chatrchyan and G Hmayakyan and V Khachatryan and A M Sirunyan and W Adam and T Bauer and T Bergauer and H Bergauer and M Dragicevic and J Erö and M Fried
l and R Frühwirth and V M Ghete and P Glaser and C Hartl and N Hoermann and J Hrubec and S Hänsel and M Jeitler and K Kastner and M Krammer and I Magrans de Abril and M Markytan an
d I Mikulec and B Neuherz and T Nöbauer and M Oberegger and M Padrta and M Pernicka and P Porth and H Rohringer and S Schmid and T Schreiner and R Stark and H Steininger and J Stra
uss and A Taurok and D Uhl and W Waltenberger and G Walzel and E Widl and C-E Wulz and V Petrov and V Prosolovich and V Chekhovsky and O Dvornikov and I Emeliantchik and A Litomin 
and V Makarenko and I Marfin and V Mossolov and N Shumeiko and A Solin and R Stefanovitch and J Suarez Gonzalez and A Tikhonov and A Fedorov and M Korzhik and O Missevitch and R Zu
yeuski and W Beaumont and M Cardaci and E De Langhe and E A De Wolf and E Delmeire and S Ochesanu and M Tasevsky and P Van Mechelen and J D'Hondt and S De Weirdt and O Devroede and
 R Goorens and S Hannaert and J Heyninck and J Maes and M U Mozer and S Tavernier and W Van Doninck and L Van Lancker and P Van Mulders and I Villella and C Wastiels and C Yu and O
 Bouhali and O Charaf and B Clerbaux and P De Harenne and G De Lentdecker and J P Dewulf and S Elgammal and R Gindroz and G H Hammad and T Mahmoud and L Neukermans and M Pins and R
 Pins and S Rugovac and J Stefanescu and V Sundararajan and C Vander Velde and P Vanlaer and J Wickens and M Tytgat and S Assouak and J L Bonnet and G Bruno and J Caudron and B De 
Callatay and J De Favereau De Jeneret and S De Visscher and P Demin and D Favart and C Felix and B Florins and E Forton and A Giammanco and G Grégoire and M Jonckman and D Kcira an
d T Keutgen and V Lemaitre and D Michotte and O Militaru and S Ovyn and T Pierzchala and K Piotrzkowski and V Roberfroid and X Rouby and N Schul and O Van der Aa and N Beliy and E 
Daubie and P Herquet and G Alves and M E Pol and M H G Souza and M Vaz and D De Jesus Damiao and V Oguri and A Santoro and A Sznajder and E De Moraes Gregores and R L Iope and S F 
Novaes and T Tomei and T Anguelov and G Antchev and I Atanasov and J Damgov and N Darmenov and L Dimitrov and V Genchev and P Iaydjiev and A Marinov and S Piperov and S Stoykova an
d G Sultanov and R Trayanov and I Vankov and C Cheshkov and A Dimitrov and M Dyulendarova and I Glushkov and V Kozhuharov and L Litov and M Makariev and E Marinova and S Markov and
 M Mateev and I Nasteva and B Pavlov and P Petev and P Petkov and V Spassov and Z Toteva and V Velev and V Verguilov and J G Bian and G M Chen and H S Chen and M Chen and C H Jiang
 and B Liu and X Y Shen and H S Sun and J Tao and J Wang and M Yang and Z Zhang and W R Zhao and H L Zhuang and Y Ban and J Cai and Y C Ge and S Liu and H T Liu and L Liu and S J Q
ian and Q Wang and Z H Xue and Z C Yang and Y L Ye and J Ying and P J Li and J Liao and Z L Xue and D S Yan and H Yuan and C A Carrillo Montoya and J C Sanabria and N Godinovic and
 I Puljak and I Soric and Z Antunovic and M Dzelalija and K Marasovic and V Brigljevic and K Kadija and S Morovic and R Fereos and C Nicolaou and A Papadakis and F Ptochos and P A 
Razis and D Tsiakkouri and Z Zinonos and A Hektor and M Kadastik and K Kannike and E Lippmaa and M Müntel and M Raidal and L Rebane and P A Aarnio and E Anttila and K Banzuzi and P
 Bulteau and S Czellar and N Eiden and C Eklund and P Engstrom and A Heikkinen and A Honkanen and J Härkönen and V Karimäki and H M Katajisto and R Kinnunen and J Klem and J Kortes
maa and M Kotamäki and A Kuronen and T Lampén and K Lassila-Perini and V Lefébure and S Lehti and T Lindén and P R Luukka and S Michal and F Moura Brigido and T Mäenpää and T Nyman
 and J Nystén and E Pietarinen and K Skog and K Tammi and E Tuominen and J Tuominiemi and D Ungaro and T P Vanhala and L Wendland and C Williams and M Iskanius and A Korpela and G 
Polese and T Tuuva and G Bassompierre and A Bazan and P Y David and J Ditta and G Drobychev and N Fouque and J P Guillaud and V Hermel and A Karneyeu and T Le Flour and S Lieunard 
and M Maire and P Mendiburu and P Nedelec and J P Peigneux and M Schneegans and D Sillou and J P Vialle and M Anfreville and J P Bard and P Besson and E Bougamont and M Boyer and P
 Bredy and R Chipaux and M Dejardin and D Denegri and J Descamps and B Fabbro and J L Faure and S Ganjour and F X Gentit and A Givernaud and P Gras and G Hamel de Monchenault and P
 Jarry and C Jeanney and F Kircher and M C Lemaire and Y Lemoigne and B Levesy and E Locci and J P Lottin and I Mandjavidze and M Mur and J P Pansart and A Payn and J Rander and J 
M Reymond and J Rolquin and F Rondeaux and A Rosowsky and J Y A Rousse and Z H Sun and J Tartas and A Van Lysebetten and P Venault and P Verrecchia and M Anduze and J Badier and S 
Baffioni and M Bercher and C Bernet and U Berthon and J Bourotte and A Busata and P Busson and M Cerutti and D Chamont and C Charlot and C Collard and A Debraine and D Decotigny an
d L Dobrzynski and O Ferreira and Y Geerebaert and J Gilly and C Gregory and L Guevara Riveros and M Haguenauer and A Karar and B Koblitz and D Lecouturier and A Mathieu and G Mill
eret and P Miné and P Paganini and P Poilleux and N Pukhaeva and N Regnault and T Romanteau and I Semeniouk and Y Sirois and C Thiebaux and J C Vanel and A Zabi and J L Agram and A
 Albert and L Anckenmann and J Andrea and F Anstotz and A M Bergdolt and J D Berst and R Blaes and D Bloch and J M Brom and J Cailleret and F Charles and E Christophel and G Claus 
and J Coffin and C Colledani and J Croix and E Dangelser and N Dick and F Didierjean and F Drouhin and W Dulinski and J P Ernenwein and R Fang and J C Fontaine and G Gaudiot and W 
Geist and D Gelé and T Goeltzenlichter and U Goerlach and P Graehling and L Gross and C Guo Hu and J M Helleboid and T Henkes and M Hoffer and C Hoffmann and J Hosselet and L Houch
u and Y Hu and D Huss and C Illinger and F Jeanneau and P Juillot and T Kachelhoffer and M R Kapp and H Kettunen and L Lakehal Ayat and A C Le Bihan and A Lounis and C Maazouzi and
 V Mack and P Majewski and D Mangeol and J Michel and S Moreau and C Olivetto and A Pallarès and Y Patois and P Pralavorio and C Racca and Y Riahi and I Ripp-Baudot and P Schmitt a
nd J P Schunck and G Schuster and B Schwaller and M H Sigward and J L Sohler and J Speck and R Strub and T Todorov and R Turchetta and P Van Hove and D Vintache and A Zghiche and M
 Ageron and J E Augustin and C Baty and G Baulieu and M Bedjidian and J Blaha and A Bonnevaux and G Boudoul and P Brunet and E Chabanat and E C Chabert and R Chierici and V Chorowi
cz and C Combaret and D Contardo and R Della Negra and P Depasse and O Drapier and M Dupanloup and T Dupasquier and H El Mamouni and N Estre and J Fay and S Gascon and N Giraud and
 C Girerd and G Guillot and R Haroutunian and B Ille and M Lethuillier and N Lumb and C Martin and H Mathez and G Maurelli and S Muanza and P Pangaud and S Perries and O Ravat and 
E Schibler and F Schirra and G Smadja and S Tissot and B Trocme and S Vanzetto and J P Walder and Y Bagaturia and D Mjavia and A Mzhavia and Z Tsamalaidze and V Roinishvili and R A
dolphi and G Anagnostou and R Brauer and W Braunschweig and H Esser and L Feld and W Karpinski and A Khomich and K Klein and C Kukulies and K Lübelsmeyer and J Olzem and A Ostaptch
ouk and D Pandoulas and G Pierschel and F Raupach and S Schael and A Schultz von Dratzig and G Schwering and R Siedling and M Thomas and M Weber and B Wittmer and M Wlochal and F A
damczyk and A Adolf and G Altenhöfer and S Bechstein and S Bethke and P Biallass and O Biebel and M Bontenackels and K Bosseler and A Böhm and M Erdmann and H Faissner and B Fehr a
nd H Fesefeldt and G Fetchenhauer and J Frangenheim and J H Frohn and J Grooten and T Hebbeker and S Hermann and E Hermens and G Hilgers and K Hoepfner and C Hof and E Jacobi and S
 Kappler and M Kirsch and P Kreuzer and R Kupper and H R Lampe and D Lanske and R Mameghani and A Meyer and S Meyer and T Moers and E Müller and R Pahlke and B Philipps and D Rein 
and H Reithler and W Reuter and P Rütten and S Schulz and H Schwarthoff and W Sobek and M Sowa and T Stapelberg and H Szczesny and H Teykal and D Teyssier and H Tomme and W Tomme a
nd M Tonutti and O Tsigenov and J Tutas and J Vandenhirtz and H Wagner and M Wegner and C Zeidler and F Beissel and M Davids and M Duda and G Flügge and M Giffels and T Hermanns an
d D Heydhausen and S Kalinin and S Kasselmann and G Kaussen and T Kress and A Linn and A Nowack and L Perchalla and M Poettgens and O Pooth and P Sauerland and A Stahl and D Tornie
r and M H Zoeller and U Behrens and K Borras and A Flossdorf and D Hatton and B Hegner and M Kasemann and R Mankel and A Meyer and J Mnich and C Rosemann and C Youngman and W D Zeu
ner and F Bechtel and P Buhmann and E Butz and G Flucke and R H Hamdorf and U Holm and R Klanner and U Pein and N Schirm and P Schleper and G Steinbrück and R Van Staa and R Wolf a
nd B Atz and T Barvich and P Blüm and F Boegelspacher and H Bol and Z Y Chen and S Chowdhury and W De Boer and P Dehm and G Dirkes and M Fahrer and U Felzmann and M Frey and A Furg
eri and E Gregoriev and F Hartmann and F Hauler and S Heier and K Kärcher and B Ledermann and S Mueller and Th Müller and D Neuberger and C Piasecki and G Quast and K Rabbertz and 
A Sabellek and A Scheurer and F P Schilling and H J Simonis and A Skiba and P Steck and A Theel and W H Thümmel and A Trunov and A Vest and T Weiler and C Weiser and S Weseler and 
V Zhukov and M Barone and G Daskalakis and N Dimitriou and G Fanourakis and C Filippidis and T Geralis and C Kalfas and K Karafasoulis and A Koimas and A Kyriakis and S Kyriazopoul
ou and D Loukas and A Markou and C Markou and N Mastroyiannopoulos and C Mavrommatis and J Mousa and I Papadakis and E Petrakou and I Siotis and K Theofilatos and S Tzamarias and A
 Vayaki and G Vermisoglou and A Zachariadou and L Gouskos and G Karapostoli and P Katsas and A Panagiotou and C Papadimitropoulos and X Aslanoglou and I Evangelou and P Kokkas and 
N Manthos and I Papadopoulos and F A Triantis and G Bencze and L Boldizsar and G Debreczeni and C Hajdu and P Hidas and D Horvath and P Kovesarki and A Laszlo and G Odor and G Pata
y and F Sikler and G Veres and G Vesztergombi and P Zalan and A Fenyvesi and J Imrek and J Molnar and D Novak and J Palinkas and G Szekely and N Beni and A Kapusi and G Marian and 
B Radics and P Raics and Z Szabo and Z Szillasi and Z L Trocsanyi and G Zilizi and H S Bawa and S B Beri and V Bhandari and V Bhatnagar and M Kaur and J M Kohli and A Kumar and B S
ingh and J B Singh and S Arora and S Bhattacharya and S Chatterji and S Chauhan and B C Choudhary and P Gupta and M Jha and K Ranjan and R K Shivpuri and A K Srivastava and R K Cho
udhury and D Dutta and M Ghodgaonkar and S Kailas and S K Kataria and A K Mohanty and L M Pant and P Shukla and A Topkar and T Aziz and Sunanda Banerjee and S Bose and S Chendvanka
r and P V Deshpande and M Guchait and A Gurtu and M Maity and G Majumder and K Mazumdar and A Nayak and M R Patil and S Sharma and K Sudhakar and B S Acharya and Sudeshna Banerjee 
and S Bheesette and S Dugad and S D Kalmani and V R Lakkireddi and N K Mondal and N Panyam and P Verma and H Arfaei and M Hashemi and M Mohammadi Najafabadi and A Moshaii and S Pak
tinat Mehdiabadi and M Felcini and M Grunewald and K Abadjiev and M Abbrescia and L Barbone and P Cariola and F Chiumarulo and A Clemente and A Colaleo and D Creanza and N De Filip
pis and M De Palma and G De Robertis and G Donvito and R Ferorelli and L Fiore and M Franco and D Giordano and R Guida and G Iaselli and N Lacalamita and F Loddo and G Maggi and M 
Maggi and N Manna and B Marangelli and M S Mennea and S My and S Natali and S Nuzzo and G Papagni and C Pinto and A Pompili and G Pugliese and A Ranieri and F Romano and G Roselli 
and G Sala and G Selvaggi and L Silvestris and P Tempesta and R Trentadue and S Tupputi and G Zito and G Abbiendi and W Bacchi and C Battilana and A C Benvenuti and M Boldini and D
 Bonacorsi and S Braibant-Giacomelli and V D Cafaro and P Capiluppi and A Castro and F R Cavallo and C Ciocca and G Codispoti and M Cuffiani and I D'Antone and G M Dallavalle and F
 Fabbri and A Fanfani and S Finelli and P Giacomelli and V Giordano and M Giunta and C Grandi and M Guerzoni and L Guiducci and S Marcellini and G Masetti and A Montanari and F L N
avarria and F Odorici and A Paolucci and G Pellegrini and A Perrotta and A M Rossi and T Rovelli and G P Siroli and G Torromeo and R Travaglini and G P Veronese and S Albergo and M
 Chiorboli and S Costa and M Galanti and G Gatto Rotondo and N Giudice and N Guardone and F Noto and R Potenza and M A Saizu and G Salemi and C Sutera and A Tricomi and C Tuve and 
L Bellucci and M Brianzi and G Broccolo and E Catacchini and V Ciulli and C Civinini and R D'Alessandro and E Focardi and S Frosali and C Genta and G Landi and P Lenzi and A Macchi
olo and F Maletta and F Manolescu and C Marchettini and L Masetti and S Mersi and M Meschini and C Minelli and S Paoletti and G Parrini and E Scarlini and G Sguazzoni and L Benussi
 and M Bertani and S Bianco and M Caponero and D Colonna and L Daniello and F Fabbri and F Felli and M Giardoni and A La Monaca and B Ortenzi and M Pallotta and A Paolozzi and C Pa
ris and L Passamonti and D Pierluigi and B Ponzio and C Pucci and A Russo and G Saviano and P Fabbricatore and S Farinon and M Greco and R Musenich and S Badoer and L Berti and M B
iasotto and S Fantinel and E Frizziero and U Gastaldi and M Gulmini and F Lelli and G Maron and S Squizzato and N Toniolo and S Traldi and S Banfi and R Bertoni and M Bonesini and 
L Carbone and G B Cerati and F Chignoli and P D'Angelo and A De Min and P Dini and F M Farina and F Ferri and P Govoni and S Magni and M Malberti and S Malvezzi and R Mazza and D M
enasce and V Miccio and L Moroni and P Negri and M Paganoni and D Pedrini and A Pullia and S Ragazzi and N Redaelli and M Rovere and L Sala and S Sala and R Salerno and T Tabarelli
 de Fatis and V Tancini and S Taroni and A Boiano and F Cassese and C Cassese and A Cimmino and B D'Aquino and L Lista and D Lomidze and P Noli and P Paolucci and G Passeggio and D
 Piccolo and L Roscilli and C Sciacca and A Vanzanella and P Azzi and N Bacchetta and L Barcellan and M Bellato and M Benettoni and D Bisello and E Borsato and A Candelori and R Ca
rlin and L Castellani and P Checchia and L Ciano and A Colombo and E Conti and M Da Rold and F Dal Corso and M De Giorgi and M De Mattia and T Dorigo and U Dosselli and C Fanin and
 G Galet and F Gasparini and U Gasparini and A Giraldo and P Giubilato and F Gonella and A Gresele and A Griggio and P Guaita and A Kaminskiy and S Karaevskii and V Khomenkov and D
 Kostylev and S Lacaprara and I Lazzizzera and I Lippi and M Loreti and M Margoni and R Martinelli and S Mattiazzo and M Mazzucato and A T Meneguzzo and L Modenese and F Montecassi
ano and A Neviani and M Nigro and A Paccagnella and D Pantano and A Parenti and M Passaseo and R Pedrotta and M Pegoraro and G Rampazzo and S Reznikov and P Ronchese and A Sancho D
aponte and P Sartori and I Stavitskiy and M Tessaro and E Torassa and A Triossi and S Vanini and S Ventura and L Ventura and M Verlato and M Zago and F Zatti and P Zotto and G Zume
rle and P Baesso and G Belli and U Berzano and S Bricola and A Grelli and G Musitelli and R Nardò and M M Necchi and D Pagano and S P Ratti and C Riccardi and P Torre and A Vicini 
and P Vitulo and C Viviani and D Aisa and S Aisa and F Ambroglini and M M Angarano and E Babucci and D Benedetti and M Biasini and G M Bilei and S Bizzaglia and M T Brunetti and B 
Caponeri and B Checcucci and R Covarelli and N Dinu and L Fanò and L Farnesini and M Giorgi and P Lariccia and G Mantovani and F Moscatelli and D Passeri and A Piluso and P Placidi
 and V Postolache and R Santinelli and A Santocchia and L Servoli and D Spiga and others},
    collaboration = {CMS},
    title         = {The CMS experiment at the CERN LHC},
    journal       = {Journal of Instrumentation},
    volume        = {3},
    number        = {08},
    pages         = {S08004},
    url           = {http://stacks.iop.org/1748-0221/3/i=08/a=S08004},
    doi           = {10.1088/1748-0221/3/08/S08004},
    year          = {2008}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{CMS_experiment}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Biber 2.7:

```
$ time biber biblatex-test
INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'biblatex-test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'biblatex-test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'biblatex-test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to biblatex-test.bbl

real    0m1.931s
user    0m1.556s
sys 0m0.260s
```

Biber 2.8:

```
$ time biber biblatex-test
INFO - This is Biber 2.8
INFO - Logfile is 'biblatex-test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'biblatex-test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'biblatex-test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to biblatex-test.bbl

real    0m15.891s
user    0m15.411s
sys 0m0.301s
```

Comment: I get 11 seconds, but it's long time nonetheless. And I get 1.6 seconds with Biber 2.7. Mac OS X Sierra here.

Comment: I did the tests on scientific linux 6 with TeXLive17. With OS X High Sierra I get similar values.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to use `backend=bibtex`? It does what I need, and it is very fast.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer BibTeX is faster because it supports only a limited set of features compared to Biber. BibTeX has been a 'legacy backend' for quite some time now and its use is discouraged (unless you know exactly what you are signing up for) because it simply can not give `biblatex` everything that Biber can.

Comment: Biber 2.8 has a new name disambiguation scheme going, since you have many names in your file that could be a bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, this is the case - there is a new system for tracking `uniquename` which saves the information needed for arbitrary name parts. This was needed to complete name generalisation. I consider such cases edge cases as that's a huge name list which needs disambiguation markers saving for every name position. If you want to speed it up during document development, just put in a source map to truncate name lists to one or two names until you want to run the final compile. I can't really help this - `bibtex` does about do 20% of what `biber` is doing.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer The reason for me to use Biber instead of BibTeX as backend was that I wanted to add extra fields and define rules how to handle them (similar to what is done here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333279/use-collaboration-field-with-biblatex-and-biber/333280).

Comment: Ok, I have run a code profiler on this name list beast example and I see perhaps some optimisations. Since I have to release 2.9 soon anyway due to a tool mode bug, I think something can be done. Watch this space.

Comment: @PLK Ok, great! I'll post your proposed workaround for document development as an answer.

Comment: @luki Workaround: As your author list is already incomplete (marked by `and others` at the end), you could simply delete all but the first few authors.

Comment: Please try biber 2.9 DEV from the development folder on SF. If you are not using the `uniquename` option in biblatex, this should be faster now. If you are using this option, then the new, more comprehensive name handling in 2.8+ will take a bit longer and you should truncate such monster lists with a map during heavy compilation iterations.

Comment: @PLK Nice. Biber 2.9 beta needs 3.5 sec.

Comment: I have just updated 2.9 DEV again. I found a huge optimisation which means that even with `uniquename` enabled, this shouldn't be bad now. On my machine, it reduces the time with this example and `uniquename` enabled from 5 mins to 14 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround during document development the author field can be truncated to a single author with a source map.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\A(.+?)\s+and\s.*}, replace={$1}]
        }
    }
}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{CMS_experiment,
    author        = {S Chatrchyan and G Hmayakyan and V Khachatryan and A M Sirunyan and W Adam and T Bauer and T Bergauer and H Bergauer and M Dragicevic and J Erö and M Fried
l and R Frühwirth and V M Ghete and P Glaser and C Hartl and N Hoermann and J Hrubec and S Hänsel and M Jeitler and K Kastner and M Krammer and I Magrans de Abril and M Markytan an
d I Mikulec and B Neuherz and T Nöbauer and M Oberegger and M Padrta and M Pernicka and P Porth and H Rohringer and S Schmid and T Schreiner and R Stark and H Steininger and J Stra
uss and A Taurok and D Uhl and W Waltenberger and G Walzel and E Widl and C-E Wulz and V Petrov and V Prosolovich and V Chekhovsky and O Dvornikov and I Emeliantchik and A Litomin 
and V Makarenko and I Marfin and V Mossolov and N Shumeiko and A Solin and R Stefanovitch and J Suarez Gonzalez and A Tikhonov and A Fedorov and M Korzhik and O Missevitch and R Zu
yeuski and W Beaumont and M Cardaci and E De Langhe and E A De Wolf and E Delmeire and S Ochesanu and M Tasevsky and P Van Mechelen and J D'Hondt and S De Weirdt and O Devroede and
 R Goorens and S Hannaert and J Heyninck and J Maes and M U Mozer and S Tavernier and W Van Doninck and L Van Lancker and P Van Mulders and I Villella and C Wastiels and C Yu and O
 Bouhali and O Charaf and B Clerbaux and P De Harenne and G De Lentdecker and J P Dewulf and S Elgammal and R Gindroz and G H Hammad and T Mahmoud and L Neukermans and M Pins and R
 Pins and S Rugovac and J Stefanescu and V Sundararajan and C Vander Velde and P Vanlaer and J Wickens and M Tytgat and S Assouak and J L Bonnet and G Bruno and J Caudron and B De 
Callatay and J De Favereau De Jeneret and S De Visscher and P Demin and D Favart and C Felix and B Florins and E Forton and A Giammanco and G Grégoire and M Jonckman and D Kcira an
d T Keutgen and V Lemaitre and D Michotte and O Militaru and S Ovyn and T Pierzchala and K Piotrzkowski and V Roberfroid and X Rouby and N Schul and O Van der Aa and N Beliy and E 
Daubie and P Herquet and G Alves and M E Pol and M H G Souza and M Vaz and D De Jesus Damiao and V Oguri and A Santoro and A Sznajder and E De Moraes Gregores and R L Iope and S F 
Novaes and T Tomei and T Anguelov and G Antchev and I Atanasov and J Damgov and N Darmenov and L Dimitrov and V Genchev and P Iaydjiev and A Marinov and S Piperov and S Stoykova an
d G Sultanov and R Trayanov and I Vankov and C Cheshkov and A Dimitrov and M Dyulendarova and I Glushkov and V Kozhuharov and L Litov and M Makariev and E Marinova and S Markov and
 M Mateev and I Nasteva and B Pavlov and P Petev and P Petkov and V Spassov and Z Toteva and V Velev and V Verguilov and J G Bian and G M Chen and H S Chen and M Chen and C H Jiang
 and B Liu and X Y Shen and H S Sun and J Tao and J Wang and M Yang and Z Zhang and W R Zhao and H L Zhuang and Y Ban and J Cai and Y C Ge and S Liu and H T Liu and L Liu and S J Q
ian and Q Wang and Z H Xue and Z C Yang and Y L Ye and J Ying and P J Li and J Liao and Z L Xue and D S Yan and H Yuan and C A Carrillo Montoya and J C Sanabria and N Godinovic and
 I Puljak and I Soric and Z Antunovic and M Dzelalija and K Marasovic and V Brigljevic and K Kadija and S Morovic and R Fereos and C Nicolaou and A Papadakis and F Ptochos and P A 
Razis and D Tsiakkouri and Z Zinonos and A Hektor and M Kadastik and K Kannike and E Lippmaa and M Müntel and M Raidal and L Rebane and P A Aarnio and E Anttila and K Banzuzi and P
 Bulteau and S Czellar and N Eiden and C Eklund and P Engstrom and A Heikkinen and A Honkanen and J Härkönen and V Karimäki and H M Katajisto and R Kinnunen and J Klem and J Kortes
maa and M Kotamäki and A Kuronen and T Lampén and K Lassila-Perini and V Lefébure and S Lehti and T Lindén and P R Luukka and S Michal and F Moura Brigido and T Mäenpää and T Nyman
 and J Nystén and E Pietarinen and K Skog and K Tammi and E Tuominen and J Tuominiemi and D Ungaro and T P Vanhala and L Wendland and C Williams and M Iskanius and A Korpela and G 
Polese and T Tuuva and G Bassompierre and A Bazan and P Y David and J Ditta and G Drobychev and N Fouque and J P Guillaud and V Hermel and A Karneyeu and T Le Flour and S Lieunard 
and M Maire and P Mendiburu and P Nedelec and J P Peigneux and M Schneegans and D Sillou and J P Vialle and M Anfreville and J P Bard and P Besson and E Bougamont and M Boyer and P
 Bredy and R Chipaux and M Dejardin and D Denegri and J Descamps and B Fabbro and J L Faure and S Ganjour and F X Gentit and A Givernaud and P Gras and G Hamel de Monchenault and P
 Jarry and C Jeanney and F Kircher and M C Lemaire and Y Lemoigne and B Levesy and E Locci and J P Lottin and I Mandjavidze and M Mur and J P Pansart and A Payn and J Rander and J 
M Reymond and J Rolquin and F Rondeaux and A Rosowsky and J Y A Rousse and Z H Sun and J Tartas and A Van Lysebetten and P Venault and P Verrecchia and M Anduze and J Badier and S 
Baffioni and M Bercher and C Bernet and U Berthon and J Bourotte and A Busata and P Busson and M Cerutti and D Chamont and C Charlot and C Collard and A Debraine and D Decotigny an
d L Dobrzynski and O Ferreira and Y Geerebaert and J Gilly and C Gregory and L Guevara Riveros and M Haguenauer and A Karar and B Koblitz and D Lecouturier and A Mathieu and G Mill
eret and P Miné and P Paganini and P Poilleux and N Pukhaeva and N Regnault and T Romanteau and I Semeniouk and Y Sirois and C Thiebaux and J C Vanel and A Zabi and J L Agram and A
 Albert and L Anckenmann and J Andrea and F Anstotz and A M Bergdolt and J D Berst and R Blaes and D Bloch and J M Brom and J Cailleret and F Charles and E Christophel and G Claus 
and J Coffin and C Colledani and J Croix and E Dangelser and N Dick and F Didierjean and F Drouhin and W Dulinski and J P Ernenwein and R Fang and J C Fontaine and G Gaudiot and W 
Geist and D Gelé and T Goeltzenlichter and U Goerlach and P Graehling and L Gross and C Guo Hu and J M Helleboid and T Henkes and M Hoffer and C Hoffmann and J Hosselet and L Houch
u and Y Hu and D Huss and C Illinger and F Jeanneau and P Juillot and T Kachelhoffer and M R Kapp and H Kettunen and L Lakehal Ayat and A C Le Bihan and A Lounis and C Maazouzi and
 V Mack and P Majewski and D Mangeol and J Michel and S Moreau and C Olivetto and A Pallarès and Y Patois and P Pralavorio and C Racca and Y Riahi and I Ripp-Baudot and P Schmitt a
nd J P Schunck and G Schuster and B Schwaller and M H Sigward and J L Sohler and J Speck and R Strub and T Todorov and R Turchetta and P Van Hove and D Vintache and A Zghiche and M
 Ageron and J E Augustin and C Baty and G Baulieu and M Bedjidian and J Blaha and A Bonnevaux and G Boudoul and P Brunet and E Chabanat and E C Chabert and R Chierici and V Chorowi
cz and C Combaret and D Contardo and R Della Negra and P Depasse and O Drapier and M Dupanloup and T Dupasquier and H El Mamouni and N Estre and J Fay and S Gascon and N Giraud and
 C Girerd and G Guillot and R Haroutunian and B Ille and M Lethuillier and N Lumb and C Martin and H Mathez and G Maurelli and S Muanza and P Pangaud and S Perries and O Ravat and 
E Schibler and F Schirra and G Smadja and S Tissot and B Trocme and S Vanzetto and J P Walder and Y Bagaturia and D Mjavia and A Mzhavia and Z Tsamalaidze and V Roinishvili and R A
dolphi and G Anagnostou and R Brauer and W Braunschweig and H Esser and L Feld and W Karpinski and A Khomich and K Klein and C Kukulies and K Lübelsmeyer and J Olzem and A Ostaptch
ouk and D Pandoulas and G Pierschel and F Raupach and S Schael and A Schultz von Dratzig and G Schwering and R Siedling and M Thomas and M Weber and B Wittmer and M Wlochal and F A
damczyk and A Adolf and G Altenhöfer and S Bechstein and S Bethke and P Biallass and O Biebel and M Bontenackels and K Bosseler and A Böhm and M Erdmann and H Faissner and B Fehr a
nd H Fesefeldt and G Fetchenhauer and J Frangenheim and J H Frohn and J Grooten and T Hebbeker and S Hermann and E Hermens and G Hilgers and K Hoepfner and C Hof and E Jacobi and S
 Kappler and M Kirsch and P Kreuzer and R Kupper and H R Lampe and D Lanske and R Mameghani and A Meyer and S Meyer and T Moers and E Müller and R Pahlke and B Philipps and D Rein 
and H Reithler and W Reuter and P Rütten and S Schulz and H Schwarthoff and W Sobek and M Sowa and T Stapelberg and H Szczesny and H Teykal and D Teyssier and H Tomme and W Tomme a
nd M Tonutti and O Tsigenov and J Tutas and J Vandenhirtz and H Wagner and M Wegner and C Zeidler and F Beissel and M Davids and M Duda and G Flügge and M Giffels and T Hermanns an
d D Heydhausen and S Kalinin and S Kasselmann and G Kaussen and T Kress and A Linn and A Nowack and L Perchalla and M Poettgens and O Pooth and P Sauerland and A Stahl and D Tornie
r and M H Zoeller and U Behrens and K Borras and A Flossdorf and D Hatton and B Hegner and M Kasemann and R Mankel and A Meyer and J Mnich and C Rosemann and C Youngman and W D Zeu
ner and F Bechtel and P Buhmann and E Butz and G Flucke and R H Hamdorf and U Holm and R Klanner and U Pein and N Schirm and P Schleper and G Steinbrück and R Van Staa and R Wolf a
nd B Atz and T Barvich and P Blüm and F Boegelspacher and H Bol and Z Y Chen and S Chowdhury and W De Boer and P Dehm and G Dirkes and M Fahrer and U Felzmann and M Frey and A Furg
eri and E Gregoriev and F Hartmann and F Hauler and S Heier and K Kärcher and B Ledermann and S Mueller and Th Müller and D Neuberger and C Piasecki and G Quast and K Rabbertz and 
A Sabellek and A Scheurer and F P Schilling and H J Simonis and A Skiba and P Steck and A Theel and W H Thümmel and A Trunov and A Vest and T Weiler and C Weiser and S Weseler and 
V Zhukov and M Barone and G Daskalakis and N Dimitriou and G Fanourakis and C Filippidis and T Geralis and C Kalfas and K Karafasoulis and A Koimas and A Kyriakis and S Kyriazopoul
ou and D Loukas and A Markou and C Markou and N Mastroyiannopoulos and C Mavrommatis and J Mousa and I Papadakis and E Petrakou and I Siotis and K Theofilatos and S Tzamarias and A
 Vayaki and G Vermisoglou and A Zachariadou and L Gouskos and G Karapostoli and P Katsas and A Panagiotou and C Papadimitropoulos and X Aslanoglou and I Evangelou and P Kokkas and 
N Manthos and I Papadopoulos and F A Triantis and G Bencze and L Boldizsar and G Debreczeni and C Hajdu and P Hidas and D Horvath and P Kovesarki and A Laszlo and G Odor and G Pata
y and F Sikler and G Veres and G Vesztergombi and P Zalan and A Fenyvesi and J Imrek and J Molnar and D Novak and J Palinkas and G Szekely and N Beni and A Kapusi and G Marian and 
B Radics and P Raics and Z Szabo and Z Szillasi and Z L Trocsanyi and G Zilizi and H S Bawa and S B Beri and V Bhandari and V Bhatnagar and M Kaur and J M Kohli and A Kumar and B S
ingh and J B Singh and S Arora and S Bhattacharya and S Chatterji and S Chauhan and B C Choudhary and P Gupta and M Jha and K Ranjan and R K Shivpuri and A K Srivastava and R K Cho
udhury and D Dutta and M Ghodgaonkar and S Kailas and S K Kataria and A K Mohanty and L M Pant and P Shukla and A Topkar and T Aziz and Sunanda Banerjee and S Bose and S Chendvanka
r and P V Deshpande and M Guchait and A Gurtu and M Maity and G Majumder and K Mazumdar and A Nayak and M R Patil and S Sharma and K Sudhakar and B S Acharya and Sudeshna Banerjee 
and S Bheesette and S Dugad and S D Kalmani and V R Lakkireddi and N K Mondal and N Panyam and P Verma and H Arfaei and M Hashemi and M Mohammadi Najafabadi and A Moshaii and S Pak
tinat Mehdiabadi and M Felcini and M Grunewald and K Abadjiev and M Abbrescia and L Barbone and P Cariola and F Chiumarulo and A Clemente and A Colaleo and D Creanza and N De Filip
pis and M De Palma and G De Robertis and G Donvito and R Ferorelli and L Fiore and M Franco and D Giordano and R Guida and G Iaselli and N Lacalamita and F Loddo and G Maggi and M 
Maggi and N Manna and B Marangelli and M S Mennea and S My and S Natali and S Nuzzo and G Papagni and C Pinto and A Pompili and G Pugliese and A Ranieri and F Romano and G Roselli 
and G Sala and G Selvaggi and L Silvestris and P Tempesta and R Trentadue and S Tupputi and G Zito and G Abbiendi and W Bacchi and C Battilana and A C Benvenuti and M Boldini and D
 Bonacorsi and S Braibant-Giacomelli and V D Cafaro and P Capiluppi and A Castro and F R Cavallo and C Ciocca and G Codispoti and M Cuffiani and I D'Antone and G M Dallavalle and F
 Fabbri and A Fanfani and S Finelli and P Giacomelli and V Giordano and M Giunta and C Grandi and M Guerzoni and L Guiducci and S Marcellini and G Masetti and A Montanari and F L N
avarria and F Odorici and A Paolucci and G Pellegrini and A Perrotta and A M Rossi and T Rovelli and G P Siroli and G Torromeo and R Travaglini and G P Veronese and S Albergo and M
 Chiorboli and S Costa and M Galanti and G Gatto Rotondo and N Giudice and N Guardone and F Noto and R Potenza and M A Saizu and G Salemi and C Sutera and A Tricomi and C Tuve and 
L Bellucci and M Brianzi and G Broccolo and E Catacchini and V Ciulli and C Civinini and R D'Alessandro and E Focardi and S Frosali and C Genta and G Landi and P Lenzi and A Macchi
olo and F Maletta and F Manolescu and C Marchettini and L Masetti and S Mersi and M Meschini and C Minelli and S Paoletti and G Parrini and E Scarlini and G Sguazzoni and L Benussi
 and M Bertani and S Bianco and M Caponero and D Colonna and L Daniello and F Fabbri and F Felli and M Giardoni and A La Monaca and B Ortenzi and M Pallotta and A Paolozzi and C Pa
ris and L Passamonti and D Pierluigi and B Ponzio and C Pucci and A Russo and G Saviano and P Fabbricatore and S Farinon and M Greco and R Musenich and S Badoer and L Berti and M B
iasotto and S Fantinel and E Frizziero and U Gastaldi and M Gulmini and F Lelli and G Maron and S Squizzato and N Toniolo and S Traldi and S Banfi and R Bertoni and M Bonesini and 
L Carbone and G B Cerati and F Chignoli and P D'Angelo and A De Min and P Dini and F M Farina and F Ferri and P Govoni and S Magni and M Malberti and S Malvezzi and R Mazza and D M
enasce and V Miccio and L Moroni and P Negri and M Paganoni and D Pedrini and A Pullia and S Ragazzi and N Redaelli and M Rovere and L Sala and S Sala and R Salerno and T Tabarelli
 de Fatis and V Tancini and S Taroni and A Boiano and F Cassese and C Cassese and A Cimmino and B D'Aquino and L Lista and D Lomidze and P Noli and P Paolucci and G Passeggio and D
 Piccolo and L Roscilli and C Sciacca and A Vanzanella and P Azzi and N Bacchetta and L Barcellan and M Bellato and M Benettoni and D Bisello and E Borsato and A Candelori and R Ca
rlin and L Castellani and P Checchia and L Ciano and A Colombo and E Conti and M Da Rold and F Dal Corso and M De Giorgi and M De Mattia and T Dorigo and U Dosselli and C Fanin and
 G Galet and F Gasparini and U Gasparini and A Giraldo and P Giubilato and F Gonella and A Gresele and A Griggio and P Guaita and A Kaminskiy and S Karaevskii and V Khomenkov and D
 Kostylev and S Lacaprara and I Lazzizzera and I Lippi and M Loreti and M Margoni and R Martinelli and S Mattiazzo and M Mazzucato and A T Meneguzzo and L Modenese and F Montecassi
ano and A Neviani and M Nigro and A Paccagnella and D Pantano and A Parenti and M Passaseo and R Pedrotta and M Pegoraro and G Rampazzo and S Reznikov and P Ronchese and A Sancho D
aponte and P Sartori and I Stavitskiy and M Tessaro and E Torassa and A Triossi and S Vanini and S Ventura and L Ventura and M Verlato and M Zago and F Zatti and P Zotto and G Zume
rle and P Baesso and G Belli and U Berzano and S Bricola and A Grelli and G Musitelli and R Nardò and M M Necchi and D Pagano and S P Ratti and C Riccardi and P Torre and A Vicini 
and P Vitulo and C Viviani and D Aisa and S Aisa and F Ambroglini and M M Angarano and E Babucci and D Benedetti and M Biasini and G M Bilei and S Bizzaglia and M T Brunetti and B 
Caponeri and B Checcucci and R Covarelli and N Dinu and L Fanò and L Farnesini and M Giorgi and P Lariccia and G Mantovani and F Moscatelli and D Passeri and A Piluso and P Placidi
 and V Postolache and R Santinelli and A Santocchia and L Servoli and D Spiga and others},
    collaboration = {CMS},
    title         = {The CMS experiment at the CERN LHC},
    journal       = {Journal of Instrumentation},
    volume        = {3},
    number        = {08},
    pages         = {S08004},
    url           = {http://stacks.iop.org/1748-0221/3/i=08/a=S08004},
    doi           = {10.1088/1748-0221/3/08/S08004},
    year          = {2008}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{CMS_experiment}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

CPU time:

```
$ time biber biblatex-test
INFO - This is Biber 2.8
INFO - Logfile is 'biblatex-test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'biblatex-test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'biblatex-test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to biblatex-test.bbl

real    0m1.337s
user    0m1.174s
sys 0m0.125s
```