# Redefine Biblatex field entry (or alias creating)

Tags: biblatex, biber, bibentry

I have a file in `bibtex` format with records like:

```
@BOOK{11980,
   author = "French, A. P.",
   title = "Vibrations and Waves",
   publisher = " ",
   year = 1971,
   numpages = 327,
   language = "english",
   edition = " ",
}
```

I wan to use it with `biblatex` `biber` also, but `biblatex` understand `pagetotal` entry instead of `numpages`. How can I redefine `numpages->pagetotal` without changing `.bib`-file

My MuWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{selinput}

    \SelectInputEncodingList{utf8,cp1251}
    \inputencoding{utf8}
    \usepackage[russian]{babel}

    \usepackage[mis]{xecyr}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
    \newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\No}{\ifmmode{\nfss@text{\textnumero}}\else\textnumero\fi}



\usepackage[%
            backend=biber,
            bibstyle=gost-numeric,
            language=auto,
            babel=other,
            sorting=none,
            doi=false,
            eprint=true,
            isbn=false,
            dashed=false,
                ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{e:/projects/LaTeX/MyPackage/MyBaseXe.bib}

\DeclareDefaultSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{%
\map{
\step[fieldsource=numpages, fieldtarget=pagetotal]
    }
}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{LL1,LL2,SivP5, Siv1}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get an error `Undefined control sequence. \DeclareDefaultSourcemap`

Comment: If you mean a specific page in the book, the relevant field is `pages` (§ 2.2.2 of the documentation, p. 21).

Comment: You can use a sourcemap declaration to copy the field.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I find \DeclareDefaultSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
\map{\step[typesource=numpages, typetarget=pagetotal]}
} but where can I put this code?

Comment: Somewhere in the minimal example that you didn't provide. (and imho it should be `\step[fieldsource=numpages,       fieldtarget=pagetotal]`

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer I get an error `Undefined control sequence. \DeclareDefaultSourcemap`. MEW is added above.

Comment: That command was renamed to `\DeclareDriverSourcemap`.  And I think the structure is normally `\DeclareDriverSourcemap{\maps[datatype=bibtex]{\map{\step[fieldsource=numpages, typetarget=pagetotal]}}}`.  (Untested.)

Comment: In version 1.9 of `biblatex`, there is no `DeclareDefaultSourcemap`.  I'd go with `\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype=bibtex]{\map{\step[fieldsource=numpages]\step[fieldset=pagetotal, origfieldval]}}}`. See §4.5.2 *Dynamic Modification of Data* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), especially the second example on pp. 151/152.

Comment: @jon Is there any reason for preferring of `\DeclareDriverSourcemap`? (I have never used that command in any of my documents; but it seems the default data mapping uses it, so there seems to be a difference.) I think `typetarget` in your code above should read `fieldtarget`.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68043/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65374/35864, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163787/35864.

Comment: @moewe -- No, I don't think there is a good reason.  I suggested it only because it is  the new name for the command the OP was using (can't remember which version it was changed in -- 2.something..?).  I've never actually used it either, only the `\DeclareSourcemap` one.  And you're surely right about the second correction. That's (for me) the problem of suggesting things without testing them first!

Comment: @jon Mhhh, `\DeclareDriverSourcemap` seems to have a slightly different syntax compared to `\DeclareSourcemap`, because it always applies only to one data format driver; but other than that the documentation only states it is conceptually different from mappings done via user sourcemapping. I was curious about that because I had never seen this command being used, but maybe it's just that.

Comment: @moewe -- Hmm, I see what you mean now that I looked it up.  Anyway, the issue is moot it seems.  Will delete my comments later today....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, I solved the problem.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=numpages,fieldtarget=pagetotal]
    }
  }
}
```